# Java: Accessing original class of an item inside an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's assume I have the following classes:

```
public class AnSuperClass { ... }
```

and

```
public class AnBetterClass extends AnSuperClass { ... }
```

Also I have the following ArrayList:

```
private final ArrayList<AnSuperClass> theList;
```

and I put some object of type AnBetterClass and AnSuperClass in it like so:

```
theList.add(new AnBetterClass());
theList.add(new AnSuperClass());
```

If I iterate over the list: how do I know which one of the two classes I have? The following query will always return false:

```
boolean foundOther = false;
for(AnSuperClass asc: theList)
    if(!(asc instanceof AnSuperClass))
        foundOther = true;
return foundOther;
```

Help desirable

P.S. Annotation do not work either.

Comment: `instanceof` checks the entire hierarchy. A `AnBetterClass` is a `AnSuperClass`.

Comment: Yes I know but I have totally no clue how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getClass()` method

```
    ArrayList<AnSuperClass> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    theList.add(new AnBetterClass());
    theList.add(new AnSuperClass());
    for(AnSuperClass asc: theList)
        System.out.println(asc.getClass());
```

that prints out

```
class pck.AnBetterClass
class pck.AnSuperClass
```